# Как узнать, что пользователь закрыл станицу?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Как на Java Spring Boot узнать, что пользователь закрыл станицу?

Хочу чтобы когда пользователь закрывал станицу, удалялся файл.

Comment: session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60); может так?

Comment: Сохраняйте время последнего обращения пользователя и удаляйте файл через какое-то время

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Spring Boot - никак.

Но вот в Javascript, с которым непосредственно взаимодействует браузер и пользователь, существуют события [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) и [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), которые вызываются перед закрытием страницы (даже если пользователь переходит по ссылке с сайта).

Реализация слушателя будет зависеть от javascript-фреймворка, который вы используете на фронте, но алгоритм будет примерно следующий:

1. Написать в js-коде хэндлер любого из этих событий, который будет отправлять сообщение о срабатывании события на сервер
2. На сервере настроить отдельный контроллер для обработки этого события (следование концепции единственной ответственности - не нужно сваливать все в кучу в один контроллер), искать и удалять файл по пришествии события.